# Website caching issue

Tags: php, html, apache, http

The issue is, I am updating code for the website. But when I browse the site, it keeps loading the older version for hours. Then after say 2-3 hours, the updated site loads.

I have been trying to update the website, but with this delay, its really difficult to make the changes.

I tried clearing my browsers cache, tried a different browser also tried private browsing mode. But nothing seems to work

The domain name is `amazist.com`

When I request for website header. this is what i get:

```
Connect to 206.190.129.20 on port 80 ... ok

    GET / HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
    Host: amazist.com[CRLF]
    Connection: close[CRLF]
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10[CRLF]
    Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
    Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
    Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
    Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
    [CRLF]
```

Comment: Do you use any (caching) proxy server in your browser? have you tried a forced reload (CTRL+F5, SHIFT+F5 depending on browser)?

Comment: Yes, I did tried everything that I know.

Comment: This could be a case of the server caching the files for U. I once had this on a host. U should try to contact your host for this imo

Comment: you listed php in tags. it can be: some kind of opcache (apc, xcache, etc.)

Comment: Then I suggest the site has a server cache layer, in which case you can't really do much. Better ask the sysadmins to temporarily disable it, or work on a staging env.

Comment: If you are not using proxy, my best guess is that your Hosting provider is caching it or using a content delivery network, so it takes a while for the files to propagate to all their mirrors.

Comment: Where does this header come from: `WP-Super-Cache: Served supercache file from PHP`? That's most likely the culprit. Edit: it seems to be a [WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) you might want to disable (or maybe you can ask it to clear its cache when you've updated something)

Comment: Do you also get the older version of your `index.php`, or only the resources files such as images and scripts?

Comment: @Tzach I think just the images and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the cause is possibly some cache mechanism introduced by the web server.

You may try and solve the problem directly, but from my experience when deploying new versions to production environment, it's better to be prepared for all kinds of caches possible, for example - cache made by your client's browser, ISP, etc.

I have tried a few solutions to this problem, my current favorite is making my build script append a version number to every script / CSS file, by computing some hash on the contents of the file. This ensures that if you change the contents of your files, their name will also change so they won't be cached anywhere.

I use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) as my build script, and [gulp-rev](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-rev) for computing the hash. This can be done for images as well, although in my projects existing images doesn't change too often, so I only use it for javascript and CSS files.

I know this method might sound like an overkill, but after implementing it on several projects, I can tell for sure that it's worth the effort.

Let me know if you have more questions.